# five integer sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find a satisfactory set of five legal increasing sequences of positive integers. A satisfactory set has the following two properties:
1) every integer appears in at least 2 of the five sequences
2) no pair of integers appears in more than 1 sequence.
A "legal"sequence is one where all numbers differ by at least 2. For example the sequence of all odd integers is legal.
I have several examples of satisfactory sets when the largest integer allowed is
finite.

For example a satisfactory set when the upper limit is 9 is {1357, 369, 1468, 2479, 258}, and I have no counterexample. I would like to find either a counterexample for some finite limit, or a way of generating a satisfactory set when there is no upper limit. 
Does anybody know anything about this?

Comment: ummmm................ Why??

Comment: Gerry Myerson has answered my question with a counterexample. I am trying to understand why a certain binary zero-sum game always has value 3/5 for Player 1 (P1). P1 names a legal sequence, P2 names any two integers, and P2 wins iff the sets are disjoint. P2's strategy is simple, but apparently P1's is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the five sequences $A,B,C,D,E$. Suppose $A$ contains the numbers $u,v,w,x,y$. Then $u$ must appear somewhere else; without loss of generality, $u$ is in $B$. Then $v$ must appear somewhere else, and it can't be in $B$, so say it's in $C$. $w$ must be somewhere else, and it can't be in $B$ or $C$, so say it's in $D$. Then $x$ must be somewhere else, and it can't be in $B,C,D$, so it's in $E$. Then $y$ must be somewhere else, but there's nowhere else it can be. So $A$ can't contain as many as five numbers. So all told the five sequences can't contain more than $20$ numbers. So the upper limit can't exceed $10$.